# How do I migrate a view?

Tags: views, 8, migrations

After releasing Drupal8-beta-15 we decide to migrate some of sites to Drupal8.
I read [this article](https://www.drupal.org/node/2127611) about how to migrate to Drupal 8, But I have some problem with it, I know when I want use a `views` in another website ( in Drupal 7) I can export/import it  or also use [Features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) but now I don't know how I can migrate my views from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.

How can I migrate a view from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8?

Comment: I don't believe there is a one click solution right now but if you're game to write some code I wrote a POC about a year ago using the D8 migrate API. The source is here: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-chx-2105305/tree/core/modules/migrate_drupal/src/Plugin/migrate?h=migrate-views there are sources and process plugins. Warning, it would need significant effort to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using this module :

[Views D8 Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_d8_upgrade)

> Tentative upgrade instructions (these may change):
>
> Before upgrading your site to Drupal 8, update to the latest 7.x-3.x
> release of Views on your Drupal 7 site.
>
> **Back up your data and place your site in maintenance mode.**
> Install the 7.x-1.x release of this module.
>
> Navigate to admin/build/views_d8_upgrade and click "Perform upgrade."
> warning: This will copy your Views data and uninstall the
> Drupal 7 Views module.
>
> Follow the Drupal core instructions for
> upgrading to Drupal 8, including updating this module to its D8
> version. This will convert your old Views data (still saved in the
> database) to Drupal 8 Views.

Comment: tnx for your attention but there is not any module there !!!\

Comment: you can download any version from this link https://www.drupal.org/node/1850396/release

Comment: I don't think that will work given Drupal 7 doesn't have an upgrade path to Drupal 8.

Comment: I didn't found any file in the above link.

Comment: This module is useless has many issues.

Comment: The source code can be found at [DrupalCode](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_d8_upgrade). However, I wouldn't use it. This [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_migration) looks to be maintained...?

Answer (score 1):

There is not currently (June 2016) an upgrade path for Views to Drupal 8. If one is created, it will not be available until D8.2 is released.

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate a views from drupal 7 to drupal 8 or Drupal 9, using this module :

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_migration

Comment: Used this today for a D7 > D9, it works great. Added one minor documentation issue, essentially ensuring the naming convention is correct for your new migration config: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_migration/issues/3340278#comment-14912917

Answer (score 0):

You can get latest release by cloning, using git feature:
[git instructions for this particular module here!](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_d8_upgrade/git-instructions/)